How much force is needed to keep a 1000kg satellite at LEO in a geostationary position?
There are many advantages to keeping communication satellites at LEO, but in order to maintain communications 24/7, you either need a swarm of satellites or multiple ground stations.
Assuming it is possible to impact constant thrust to a satellite in LEO, how much force would be needed to keep an LEO satellite weighing 1000 kg geostationary?

It wouldn't be a satellite any more than a stratospheric balloon.

You'd just need as much force as its weight.

@mithrope My God, can it be that simple? That's great! The vector would have to be rotated slightly to provide the forward accelleration.

This is a straightforward calculation. What have you tried? This site is not a place to get others to do your work for you.

@MissUnderstands High-altitude balloons are really cool - benefits of geostationary satellites, none of the hassle of actual satellites (maneuvering balloons is much easier since you can use the air as reaction mass in jet engines). They're not in space but there has actually been serious proposal to use high-altitude internet balloons...

I think 1000 kg-force is a good bet. You can apply an $(R_{\oplus} + LEO) / R_{\oplus}$ correction, as needed.

Pick the frame corotating with Earth. Account for all the forces acting on the body: thrust, gravity, and centrifugal force. (Also Euler and Coriolis forces, but you will find that these drop out.) Observe that there is zero acceleration in the chosen frame. What does that tell you about the net force in the chosen frame? Thus obtain an equation with one unknown (thrust).
